# Open Source Extendable ERP Package

Tags: erp

As the title suggests I am looking for a open source ERP package. While there are tons of ERPs out there, None of them meet my needs. I am looking for a package which I can use configuration or minimal coding to create my customize ERP package for a customer. MS CRM has this ability, it has some built in modules as well we can add more module using configuration files and where needs extend the functionality using aspx of workflow (dll) modules. Please let me know if you need more info on this, I have been looking for this for sometime and yet to get something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Sugar CRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/) for the need because of its ability to customize the package.

Answer (score 0):

[IntarS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/intars/) might be your solution. Very extensible, running real world productive implementations since 10 years. Universal application architecture.

Comment: Please mention in your answers that it's your own product you're recommending as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).

Answer (score 0):

Check [erpnext.com](http://www.erpnext.com) - clean, easy to read codebase, available on gihub with an excellent team of guys supporting it.  They also offer a hosting service to go with it which is very affordable.  Your data is also safe - you can get a mysql dump of all of it at any time if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I think [ebizframe ERP software](http://www.essindia.com/ebizframe-erp-software) can meet your needs related to ERP.